# How to show all content and why can't filter by id

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
 <div class="filter hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
      <a href="?type=all" id="all">View All</a>
      <a href="?type=zoologist" id="zoologist">Zoologist</a>
      <a href="?type=hobbyist" id="hobbyist">Hobbyist</a>
      <a href="?type=judge" id="judge">Judge</a>
  </div>

<div id="accordion"></div>
```

JSON

```
 var JSONObject = [
    {
      "name": "Jonathan Suh",
      "type": "zoologist, hobbyist"
    },
    {
      "name": "William Philbin",
      "type": "judge, hobbyist"
    },
    {
      "name": "Allison McKinnery",
      "type": "hobbyist"
    }
  ];
```

Jquery

```
 $('.filter a').on('click', function(e){

              e.preventDefault();
              var filter = $(this).attr('id');

              $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://path/to/example.json,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {"type" : filter},
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                  console.log('loading');
                },
                success: function(response){
                  console.log('success');
                  var details = '';
                  for (var key in response) {
                    if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                      details+='<h1 class="name">' + response[key]["name"] + '</h1>';
                      details+='<div class="accordion-content row">'+response[key]["gender"]'</div>';

                    }
                  }

                  $('#accordion').html(details).fadeIn();

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log('XHR ' + jqXHR);
                  console.log('status ' + textStatus);
                  console.log('error ' + errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function(){
                  console.log('finished all tasks');
                }

            });
       });
```

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kittymeow/oau4q8bL/2)

Worked on $.ajax and it somehow works by showing the accordion content. There are two or three problems that I couldn't get around.

At first thought about matching with the window.location.search but ended up trying to filter by id instead.

1. you notice that i put data: {"type" : filter} which would get name from json and compare with 'filter'. It does not do anything. Why? How to filter by type in json and find all info that are filtered by type?
2. When first load the page, it doesn't show all content in accordion area. The problem is that all json is processed via $.ajax. Is there any possible way to show all content outside $.ajax? But I do not want to repeat all content if same code inside $.ajax

Comment: I assume the missed apostrophe is a problem here on SO only? url: 'http://path/to/example.json,

Comment: @Mackan it is only example but I did put json in text for u to know what is inside json file.

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying you missed to close the "url: " with an apostrophe. Regarding your first question - From the documentation of jQuery ajax data attribute: "Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests"

Comment: @Mackan - hmm and sorry im not familiar with $.ajax. Right now it shows all content just ok when click filter link, only the issue is how to filter json that is same of type as filter link's id. :(

Comment: Well, the "data" is sent to "path/to/example.json", so this is where you want to apply the filter and work with your data before you return it back to the "success".

Comment: @Mackan - it means i cant just use filter's id. By applying filter and work with data, it requires some function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems to be clear that you're not sending your "data" anywhere, you'll have to just filter the result/response.

Also, to easily solve your second question - You can just put the ajax in a function, and call this function both on "click" and on "page load".

```
function loadMyJson(filter) {

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://path/to/example.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('loading');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('success, filtering response...');

        //Filter the returned json by "filter"            
        var filteredJson = $(response).filter(function (i,n) { 
            return n.type === filter; 
        });

        var details = '';
        for (var key in filteredJson) {
            if (filteredJson.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              details+='<h1 class="name">' + filteredJson[key]["name"] + '</h1>';
              details+='<div class="accordion-content row">'+filteredJson[key]["gender"]'</div>';
            }
        }
        $('#accordion').html(details).fadeIn();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('XHR ' + jqXHR);
        console.log('status ' + textStatus);
        console.log('error ' + errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function(){
        console.log('finished all tasks');
    }
 });
}

$('.filter a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loadMyJson($(this).attr('id'));
}

loadMyJson('all'); //This is for the initial page load
```

Comment: ah with function it can work inside click event. many thanks! One question though, it seems not to access to name as error said: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined?

Comment: You'll have to debug the response, and see that it contains what you're expecting (a key named 'name' among other things)

Comment: trying now. name and description etc are there in json but it keeps giving me undefined.

Comment: I test without { var filteredJson = $(response).filter(function (i,n) { 
            return n.type === filter; 
        });} and it works by listing out [key][name]. so this part is not returning anything. hmm.

Comment: Try JSON.parse(response) before the filter, to see that it's a valid json object

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o error I got for parsing response.

Comment: ok i tried  console.log('parsing...' + response[0].name); and it shows name. maybe filterJson part is not working

Comment: What if you do console.log('parsing...' + filteredJson[0].name) right after it's set then? (just above the for loop in other words)

Comment: @joe Also, try with this instead: filteredJson[key].name and filteredJson[key].gender (notice that you're missing a + after this in your example)

Comment: console.log('parsing' + filteredJson[0].name) works. but for inside loop hasOwnproperty, filteredJson[key].name returns undefined.

Comment: missing a + after this == where are u referring to?

Comment: sorry. I got it working, but I noticed that it will return undefined if in json there are more than 1 type, i.e. type: "hobbyist", "zoologist"

Comment: @joe If this post answered your initial question(s), then please mark it as answer to close this issue. If you have more/new questions you can then post them as new question

Comment: ok it is still not returning right if it is more than 1 type. but still thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @joe it can be solved (by for example splitting the type), but ask it as a new question. We can't expect users to read 20 comments to find follow-up questions and answers.

Comment: ok. i have tried to spilt the type but it doesnt return any value. I will post soon in a few hours

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344172/how-to-spilt-the-types-which-will-have-more-than-1-in-filter - if you have time to look at it