# How to spilt the types which will have more than 1 in filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
function loadJson(filter){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://path/to/example.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
      console.log('loading');
    },
    success: function(response){

  var filteredJson = $(response).filter(function (i,n) {
        console.log('type ' + n.type);
        var type = n.type.split(',');
        for(var i=0; i<type.length;i++){
         return n.type === filter;
     }
   });
  console.log('parsing...' + filteredJson[0].name);
     //console.log('filter by json ' + filteredJson);


      for (var key in filteredJson){
        if(filteredJson.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          console.log('list ' + filteredJson[0].name);
        }
      }
      $('#accordion').html(details).fadeIn();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('XHR ' + jqXHR);
      console.log('status ' + textStatus);
      console.log('error ' + errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function(){
      console.log('finished all tasks');
    }
  })
}


$('.filter a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  loadJson($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

JSON

```
 var JSONObject = [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "type": "zoologist, hobbyist"
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "type": "judge, hobbyist"
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "type": "hobbyist"
    }
  ];
```

As you see, there are more than 1 in json: type. Tried to split inside types filterJson so that can filter through all types and print out the names.

How to spilt all the types to be processed to be filtered?

Comment: check with if (type.length > 0)

Comment: Funnily enough, the variable `JSONObject` is neither JSON nor an object.

Comment: [Didn't you ask this question some time ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330149/why-cannot-access-json) You can't use the `.filter()` function for an object—works for DOM elements only.

Comment: seems like instead `for(var i=0; i<type.length;i++){
         return n.type === filter;
     }` you need use something like `return n.type.split(',').some(function(el){return el==filter})`

Comment: @Terry filter should do the trick? - https://jsfiddle.net/vo1t6znn/

Comment: @JqueryKing - i tried already but it did not work.

Comment: @Grundy - it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Terry - i prefer filter way because I need to be able to load all content when first load page. filter itself works and print name but can't filter more than 1 type

Comment: @joe so what output expected?

Comment: @Grundy - need to be able to split more than 1 item in a type, i.e. judge and hobbyist and then can filter these items in all types. then it will find all names related to filter type. If search hobbyist, it will find me A, B and C. If zoologist, it finds me A

Comment: @joe, so what not work in my sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, I think you're looking for something like:

```
var filteredJson = $(response).filter(function (i, n) {
    return n.type && n.type.indexOf(filter) != -1;
});
```

That is: if the variable "filter" is found in any "type", then filter by it.

To test, you can do:

```
$.each(filteredJson, function () {
    console.log('Filtered list: ' + this.name);
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vo1t6znn/3/ or SO-snippet below..

```js
var varData = [{
  "name": "A",
  "type": "zoologist, hobbyist"
}, {
  "name": "B",
  "type": "judge, hobbyist"
}, {
  "name": "C",
  "type": "hobbyist"
}];

var filter = '';

$(document).on('change', '#filter', function() {
  filter = $(this).val();

  var filteredObj = $(varData).filter(function(i, n) {
    return n.type && n.type.indexOf(filter) != -1;
  });

  var output = 'Result after filter: ';
  $.each(filteredObj, function(k, v) {
    console.log('list: ' + this.name);
    output += this.name + ', ';
  });
  $('#result').html(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Filter:
<select id="filter" name="filter">
  <option value="zoologist">zoologist</option>
  <option value="hobbyist">hobbyist</option>
  <option value="judge">judge</option>
</select>
<div id="result">Change filter to start</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. it is listing name correctly, but when go into (hasOwnProperty), it shows name correctly then add a few extra undefined names which I assume it is because of the filter return?

Comment: Replace your for-loop with my $.each loop and I'm sure it will work better. You're working with an array. also, I added a testable "SO snippet" .. because I was restless ;-)

Comment: yes i already tried before I saw your answer ha. it worked yay! thanks so much. one more unrelated quick qn - if i wanted animation on accordion, it has to be inside $.ajax? because I also need animation for all.

Comment: You mean the "fadeIn()"? If so yes, if you want it to fade in after the ajax returns the data. Ofcourse this can be put in a separate function if you want to separate the code, and be called from the ajax-success.

Comment: i had different function to put slideup and slidedown then call it into ajax success. But this `$('#accordion').html(details).fadeIn();` and it doesn't really show fade or anything. thats why i asked.

Comment: The element (accordion) should probably be using "display: none;" before the fadeIn occurs. Also, you could try a slow animation, to make sure it's not "too quick to notice": .fadeIn('slow');